# how to get column markers with free text editors

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, text-editors, textpad

Can someone please provide some tips on getting column markers to show (vertical lines) when viewing text files with fixed width column based data. (not csv). Notepad++,  wordpad any freebie will do. Ultraedit/Kedit does it nicely but is not free. It does it as shown in this [link](http://www.kedit.com/hint_colmark.html) . I would have used excel but excel does not show text like a text editor. Ideally after setting column markers if I click anywhere in the file I would like to know which column it is , it's width, cursor position from start , cursor position within column. Any pointers on this will help.

Answer (score 1):

SynWrite editor (free!) has option for columns marks. Command "View - Column markers".